# JSON NO_REFERENCES

Tags: java, json, spring, xstream

I have just started using JSON...
I am using it in my project (Spring).
I am making JSON string using XStream...
I found in tutorial of XStream that using JSON, we have to set it's mode to NO_REFERENCES.
I tried out searching it's reason on various sites, but I didn't find it anywhere...
I tried removing it from my code...
But that also did not had any effect on my output...
So, tell me why we have to set it's mode to NO_REFERENCES?

Comment: Please provide a short program or code sample that reproduces the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as the tutorial says, JSON has no mechanism for handling references; duplicates must be explicitly written out. If both `foo` and `bar` point to `baz`, then `baz` will get written twice; once under `foo` and once under `bar`.